# Oracle SQL Developer intelligent hotkeys

Tags: oracle

Is there any hotkeys for Oracle SQL Developer to show intelligent code?
It  has  intelligent  when I keyin some sql Script, but always need to wait a long time ,or doen't  show intelligent code .

So,where can I set to  show intelligent code by hotkeys?
thx.

Comment: If you meant autocompletion, then it would be `CTRL+SPACE`. You can adjust its "reaction time" via `tools\preferences\code edtor\completion insigth`

Comment: Dear：Thx for your help, I had changed the completion insigth speed, it show code faster.But shome code still not show. such as: I want to type select * from emp, so I type ".. from e" then use "ctrl+space" but it doesn't show intelgent code.